# Microsoft Excel cannot access the file (Java -> cmd /c python -> Excel)

Tags: python, java, excel, cmd

I call the following Python script from my JavaEE-based API (`cmd /c python <args>` via ProcessBuilder), which accesses Excel to export a table to PDF:

```
import sys

import win32com.client

import pathlib

if len(sys.argv) < 5:
    print("Usage: %s input.xls output.pdf worksheet range" % sys.argv[0])
    exit(1)

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
o.Visible = False

wb_path = r'C:\Develop\uploadedFile_5232859756803526399.xlsx'
path_to_pdf = sys.argv[2]
worksheet_idx = sys.argv[3]
print_area = sys.argv[4]

wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)

ws = wb.Worksheets[int(worksheet_idx)]
ws.Activate()
ws.PageSetup.Zoom = False
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = print_area

wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)

wb.Close(True)
o.Quit()
```

`wb_path = r'C:\Develop\uploadedFile_5232859756803526399.xlsx` is just for testing purposes of `wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)` (`wb_path =sys.argv[1]` is also not working), which throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-01-13 14:46:24 INFO  [utils.CMDUtils]   File "C:\scripts\scriptWin.py", line 23, in <module>
2022-01-13 14:46:24 INFO  [utils.CMDUtils]     wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
2022-01-13 14:46:24 INFO  [utils.CMDUtils]   File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 5, in Open
2022-01-13 14:46:24 INFO  [utils.CMDUtils] pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\\Develop\\uploadedFile_5232859756803526399.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:\n\n• The file name or path does not exist.\n• The file is being used by another program.\n• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

What did I wrong? When I call this script directly in the CMD (via Remote Desktop) with the Administrator on my Windows 2019 Server, it runs properly.

**EDIT**

Here is my Java code snippet:

```
String catalinaBase = System.getProperty("catalina.base");
File logsFolder = new File(catalinaBase, "logs");

try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(logsFolder,"cmd.log"));) {

            List<String> python3 = new ArrayList<>();
            if(OSUtils.isWindows()){
                python3.add("cmd /c");
                python3.add("python");
            }else{
                python3.add("python3");
            }
            python3.add(quoteStr(pythonScript.getAbsolutePath()));

            if(params != null && params.size() > 0){
                params.stream().forEach(p->{
                    python3.add(quoteStr(p));
                });
            }

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(python3);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process process = OSUtils.isWindows() ?
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.join(" ", pb.command())) :
                    pb.start();

            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR", fos, log);
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", fos, log);

            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            exitVal = process.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if(!exitVal){
                errorGobbler.stopThread();
                outputGobbler.stopThread();
                process.destroyForcibly();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

StreamGobbler is similar to this one: https://gist.github.com/jmartisk/6535784

Comment: You should add Java code too, and verify in Java that the file exists and that your own code is not responsible for the "file is being used by another program".

Comment: The file exists: it was created as a temp file within the temp folder of tomcat. How can I doublecheck, if the file is still being used by Java? After creating the temp file, I only call FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(tempFile, formData.getFileData());

Comment: Just for testing purposes, I outsourced everything (with hard-coded file paths) in a .bat-file and just call this file from Java (also as an Admin) -> didn't work. If I double-clicked on the .bat-file (RDP), it worked as intended. That drives me completely crazy :D :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a setting issue.

Open DCOMCNFG, expand Component Services | My Computer | DCOM Config and find Microsoft Excel Application -> Properties -> under the Identity tab set it to "The interactive user" (RDP only) or to "This user." for background services.

[image]